# How can I find the substring of a string using delimiters and their occurences in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The string (column data) : 625625,Name1;472719,Name2;472736,Name3;

I want to fetch the numbers separately, lets say 3rd number (472736).

Comment: Try something like this substr(col,1,instr(col,',')-1). or else kindly post sample data with create and insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
   replace(regexp_substr(str, '[0-9]+[,]', 1, 3), ',', '')
```

Note that if your names did not contain digits, you could use the simpler:

```
   regexp_substr(str, '[0-9]+', 1, 3)
```